# Selenium doesn't click all of the buttons on the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have been scraping this page: https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/berlin/berlin/wohnung-kaufen.

The page has multiple apartments shown in one bundle as shown in the picture and I want to click the button (marked with red elipse) to show all of the apartments of that bundle.
[image]

My code expands the first bundle but does not expand others (some page may have 1, 5 or none of them). The code that I used is the following:

```
while True:
        try:
            show_more_units = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="result-p-149498364"]/div[3]/button')
            show_more_units.click()
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print("Show more button clicked.")

        except:
            print('No button to "Show more".')
            break
```

I have seen that each bundle button has different ID. I have tried the following as well:

```
show_more_units = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Einheiten anzeigen')]")
```

and

```
show_more_units = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'padding-left-none link-text-secondary button')
```

but none of these options helps. In fact both of these options doesn't even expand one bundle.

I want my code to expand all of the bundles before I scrape the information that I need. How can I achieve this?

Thank you upfront.

P.S. The HTML of the button is the following:

```
<button class="padding-left-none link-text-secondary button"><span class="s24-icons-s24_chevron_right_24"></span> <!-- -->3 weitere Einheiten anzeigen</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were fairly close. I changed a few things to get it to work:

1. A different locator. The CSS selector, `article button.button` matches only the desired buttons.
2. A `WebDriverWait` to ensure that the BUTTON is ready to be clicked each time.
3. My `try-except` catches specifically the `TimeoutException` from a `WebDriverWait` timing out. This should only happen after all the matching BUTTONs have been clicked and are removed from the page.

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

   url = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/berlin/berlin/wohnung-kaufen'
   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.maximize_window()
   driver.get(url)
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
   while True:
       try:
          wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"article button.button"))).click()

       except TimeoutException:
           break

   driver.quit()
   ```

---

Additional notes:

1. It's a best practice to only catch exceptions that you plan to handle. Trapping more than that can lead to hidden failures which make investigations much more difficult.
2. You should always use `WebDriverWait` before interacting with any element. It ensures that the element is ready and reduces intermittent (and sometimes deterministic) failures.
3. Avoid `time.sleep()` unless it's absolutely necessary. It will make your scripts faster and less error prone, see #2, above.
4. Your final locator attempt, `(By.CLASS_NAME, 'padding-left-none link-text-secondary button')`, is using `By.CLASS_NAME` incorrectly. It's expecting only a single class name and you sent it 3. Either choose only one of the classes or convert it to a `By.CSS_SELECTOR`, e.g. `.padding-left-none.link-text-secondary.button`.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the solutions and advice. :)